# Array.Push returns the last pushed object only..How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**I Know this question may be duplicate, but none of the other answers worked for me..** 
I am trying to send datatable valueS in an array to controller. but, `array.push()` returns the last object only.

```
<script> 
  var dd = table.rows().data().toArray();
  var data1 = new Array();
  var CData= {};

 for (i = 0; i < dd.length; i++) {
  CData.Date = dd[i][1];
  CData.Description = dd[i][2];
  data1.push(CData);
}
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/Test/Create",
contentType: "application/json;",
headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': gettoken() },
data: JSON.stringify(data1:data1),
success: function () {
 alert('success');
},
error: function () {
   alert('failure');
}
 });
</script>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly do:-

```
for (i = 0; i < dd.length; i++) {
  data1.push({
    Date: dd[i][1], 
    Description:  dd[i][2]
  });
}
```

Now these 3 line of code will be removed:-

```
var CData= {};

CData.Date = dd[i][1];
CData.Description = dd[i][2];
```

Comment: @Ben  glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are always modifying the same object and not creating a seperate one for every iteration of `dd`.

You should be creating a new one in the loop to avoid overwriting the same object each time :

```
 for (i = 0; i < dd.length; i++) {
  var CData= {}; // now new object each time
  CData.Date = dd[i][1];
  CData.Description = dd[i][2];
  data1.push(CData);
}
```

Comment: at first I tried ur one ,working for me, but @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie code reduce my code , I chose that one. THank u once again.. I will give u an upvote sir..

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, it is not recommended to declare variables inside loops (unnecessary memory allocation).

```
var dd = table.rows().data().toArray();
var data1 = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < dd.length; i++) {
  data1.push({
    Date: dd[i][1],
    Description: dd[i][2]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, CData is defined as Object.
It takes only last values because it everytime overwriting and finally last values are storing.
Instead of it, use array to store object values in it.

**Example**:

```
var dd = table.rows().data().toArray();
var data1 = new Array();
var CData= [];

for (i = 0; i < dd.length; i++) {
    CData[i] = {"Date" : dd[i][1],"Description" : dd[i][2]};
}
var required_data = JSON.stringify(CData);
```

finally send this(required_data) to ajax call.